# redux-observable error provided "false" where a stream was expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I have file epic (redux-observable) like this :

```
export const intervalChartEpic = (action$, store) => 
 action$.ofType(FETCHING_CHART_DATA_ONE_DAY_SUCCESS)
  .filter(() => (store.getState().currentPeriod === PERIOD_ONE_DAY))
  .mergeMap(() => Observable
    .interval(10000)
    .takeUntil(store.getState().currentPeriod !== PERIOD_ONE_DAY)
    .switchMap(() => ajax.getJSON(updateChartOneDayUrl(store))
     .map(response => fetchIntervalChartDataSuccess(response))
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log('============Position 1============');
       console.log(err);
       return Observable.of(fetchChartDataFailure(err));
     })
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('============Position 2============');
      console.log(err);
      return Observable.of(fetchChartDataFailure(err));
    });
  );
```

And it comes out with a **error** like

```
"You provided 'false' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."
```

Error at Position 2, it mean it error at `switchMap()` funtion, and i dont know why, can any body here help me ???, thank so much !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't actually with your `switchMap`, it's your `takeUntil`

```
.takeUntil(store.getState().currentPeriod !== PERIOD_ONE_DAY)
```

You're passing a boolean as the argument to `takeUntil`, [which expects an Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil)!

> public takeUntil(notifier: Observable): Observable

While there are fairly complex ways to take a stream until the store's state changes to a particular value, in practice I've *so far* found them to be anti-patterns. Instead, listen for for the **action** which describes the intent to change that state, whatever that action is.

```
.takeUntil(
  action$
    .ofType(CHANGE_PERIOD)
    .filter(action => action.currentPeriod !== PERIOD_ONE_DAY)
)
```

---

If you truly want to instead get a stream of state, one way of doing it is to create it and inject it into all your epics. This requires the latest version of redux-observable, [further documented here](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/InjectingDependenciesIntoEpics.html)

> To inject dependencies you can use createEpicMiddleware's `dependencies` configuration option

```
const state$ = new BehaviorSubject();

const store = createStore(
  applyMiddleware(
    createEpicMiddleware(epic, {
      dependencies: { state$ } // <-- this is important
    })
  )
);

Observable.from(store).subscribe(state$);
```

The last part, where we create an `Observable.from(store)` is because Redux's store supports `Symbol.observable`--you can just think "it just works cause we worked with them".

However, you might be tempted to just use `Observable.from(store)` on the store that your epics receive as the second argument but **this won't work** because it's not really the full store object! [Read more about why here](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/56)

Your newly injected stream of `state$` would now be in the object of the third argument to your epics

```
// third argument is object of dependencies vvvvvvvv
const intervalChartEpic = (action$, store, { $state }) =>
```

And you could use it like this:

```
.takeUntil(
  state$.filter(state => state.currentPeriod !== PERIOD_ONE_DAY)
)
```

It's unclear which approach is more "correct". The stream of state is certainly easier, but I have some coupling and timing concerns that have prevented me from actually including it in redux-observable. I'm also mostly worried about it being a footgun--making it so easy to do bad things.